# HTML5 sessionStorage : variable not stored on <li> onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, session-storage

i wonder why this onclick work on this div:

```
<div id="block-block-contact" class="block-factice expanded" onclick="sessionStorage.contactclass=this.className ">
```

but not on this li

```
 <li id="dhtml_menu-1895" class="first collapsed dhtml-menu collapsed start-collapsed menu-1895" onclick="sessionStorage.menu1895=this.className">
```

meaning when i click on the div, it does store the contactclass variable whereas when i click on the li, it does not store the menu1895 variable

Answer (score 2):

Matoeil,

Can you please check this
https://jsfiddle.net/612ee2df/

```
 <ul>
  <li id="dhtml_menu-1895" class="first collapsed dhtml-menu collapsed    start-collapsed menu-1895" onclick="sessionStorage.menu1895=this.className">
   Test
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
  $('ul li').on('click',function(e)
  {
      var cls = $(this).attr('class');
      alert(cls);
      sessionStorage.menu1895 = cls;
  })
 })
```

Because I tried your code-snippet but instead of JavaScript I used jQuery & it saved the value in  session storage.

Comment: thanks if does not work on mine though. Could it be that there is already a defaut onclick action on that li ? how can i check that and how can i change weight so my action is before the other one?

Comment: not sure in JavaScript but in jQuery there is method unbind.. call unbind() & then associate your click(), not 100% sure that it will for you,but you can try

Comment: are you adding this `li` dynamically??

Comment: there is a prototype onclick event . i dont know how to make both actions workin together

Answer (score 0):

another event was linked to this element.
To strip all event listeners i did

```
var old_element=document.getElementById("dhtml_menu-1895");     
var new_element = old_element.cloneNode(true);
old_element.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_element);
```

and now it works